# Monoid Bool in Haskell

Tags: haskell, monoids

Of course the data type is not exact, but is this how (more or less) the `Monoid Bool` is implemented?

```
import Data.Monoid

data Bool' = T | F deriving (Show)

instance Monoid (Bool') where
    mempty = T
    mappend T _ = T
    mappend _ T = T
    mappend _ _ = F
```

If so/not, what is the reasoning for making `Bool`'s `mappend` an `OR` versus `AND`?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There are two possible `Monoid` instances for `Bool`, so `Data.Monoid` has newtypes to distinguish which one we intend:

```
-- | Boolean monoid under conjunction.
newtype All = All { getAll :: Bool }
        deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Bounded, Generic)

instance Monoid All where
        mempty = All True
        All x `mappend` All y = All (x && y)

-- | Boolean monoid under disjunction.
newtype Any = Any { getAny :: Bool }
        deriving (Eq, Ord, Read, Show, Bounded, Generic)

instance Monoid Any where
        mempty = Any False
        Any x `mappend` Any y = Any (x || y)
```

Edit: There are actually four valid instances as Ørjan notes

Comment: Thank you. I'm not sure if it's a separate question entirely, but why is `newtype` used rather than `data`? Thx

Comment: `newtype` is more efficient than `data`.  Wrapping and unwrapping a newtype is free performance-wise.

Comment: There are four, actually. `(&&),(||),(==),(/=)` all are possible monoid operations. The last two aren't predefined, though.

Comment: Xor also forms a monoid.

Comment: @alternative Xor is the same monoid as `(/=)`

Comment: @GabrielGonzalez So? Still a monoid, and you said there are two possible instances. Xor is also an instance.

Comment: @alternative Right, I agree that there are actually four instances.

Comment: @AndrewC It looks to me like `True` is `mempty` for the `(==)` instance and `False` is `mempty` for the `(/=)` instance. Also, in this case, if one of those two `mempty` laws is satisfied the other one is too because both `(==)` and `(/=)` are commutative.

Comment: Can someone clarify what the `getAll` and `getAny` are? I have never seen the curly-bracket syntax before so if it's just a syntax thing, where could I find more information on it?

Comment: @2016rshah That's known as "record syntax" and you can learn more about it [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/making-our-own-types-and-typeclasses) in the section titled "Record syntax"

Comment: I would say they are 16 possible monoids (2^4) given the 16 possible binary operations coming from all the combinations of T/F for the outputs given four different inputs (FF,TF,FT,TT). Some of which could be useless (like all F or all T).

Comment: lkuty: Eight of those are ineligible because their `<>` has `T <> F /= F <> T`, which means neither `F` nor `T` is `mempty`. Two others are ineligible because their `<>` has `T <> F = F = T <> T` which means neither `F` nor `T` is `mempty`. Two others are ineligible because their `<>` has `T <> F = T = F <> F` which means neither `F` nor `T` is `mempty`.  The remaining four are `&&`, `||`, `==`, and `/=`.

Comment: @ØrjanJohansen How is `(==)` a monoid? What is the identity?

Comment: @Anabra: It's a `Monoid` when it's used to compare `Bool`s.  The identity is `True`

Answer (score 5):

Your provided instance isn't a monoid.

```
mappend F mempty
mappend F T  -- by definition of mempty
T            -- by definition of mappend
```

so we've proven `F <> mempty === T`, but for any monoid, `x <> mempty === x`.

The unit for `Any` is `False`, and the unit for `All` is `True`.